# How to get results from laravel query builder in something similar to eloquent result

Tags: php, laravel

i am running a simple query like as below in laravel:

```
        $query = DB::table('properties as p')
            ->join('companies as c','c.id','p.company_id')
            ->leftJoin('property_versions as pv','pv.property_id','p.id')
            ->leftJoin('notices as n','n.property_id','p.id')
            ->select('p.*','pv.*','c.name as company_name','n.slug','n.file_type','n.seen')
            ->orderBy('p.created_at','desc');
        $result = $query->get();
        dd($result);
```

but this one is returning results in flat array, so I try to make it nested as :

$result->groupBy(['property_id','id']); but still it is not same as the way as in eloquent results.

Is it possible to get the results in nested or grouping view or at least separating the notice related data on a different elements like:

```
[
    [
        [id] => 407
        [property_name] => dummy name
        [company_id] => 1
        [rate] => 
        [floor_file] => 2,
        [notices] => [
            [
                'slug' => UUKF2oyn
                'file_type' => 2
                'seen' => n
            ],
                        [
                'slug' => UUKF2abc
                'file_type' => 1
                'seen' => n
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [id] => 407
        [property_name] => dummy name
        [company_id] => 1
        [rate] => 
        [floor_file] => 2,
        [notices] => [
            [
                'slug' => UUKF2oyn
                'file_type' => 2
                'seen' => n
            ],
                        [
                'slug' => UUKF2abc
                'file_type' => 1
                'seen' => n
            ]
        ]
    ],

]
```

update: by using eloquent eager loading I could get results something like:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 415
            [property_name] => Test
            [company_id] => 1
            [rate] => 
            [floor_file] => 0
            [sort_offset] => 
            [calculated_offset] => 0
            [fp_property_version_id] => 
            [created_at] => 2021-04-02 20:50:34
            [updated_at] => 2021-04-02 20:50:34
            [name] => Company A
            [property_versions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 434
                            [property_name] => Test
                            [version_name] => v1
                            [property_code] => 
                            [rate] => 
                            [completed] => 1
                            [availability_file] => 0
                            [floor_file] => 0
                            [pricing_review] => 0
                            [company_id] => 1
                            [mapping_template_id] => 495
                            [created_by] => 2
                            [axis] => 0
                            [view_style] => fs
                            [sort_offset] => 
                            [calculated_offset] => 0
                            [property_id] => 415
                            [created_at] => 2021-04-04 08:52:42
                            [updated_at] => 2021-04-04 08:53:42
                            [last_uploaded_at] => 2021-04-04 08:52:42
                            [last_amenity_uploaded_at] => 2021-04-04 08:52:42
                            [notices] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 435
                            [property_name] => Test
                            [version_name] => v2
                            [property_code] => 
                            [rate] => 
                            [completed] => 1
                            [availability_file] => 0
                            [floor_file] => 0
                            [pricing_review] => 0
                            [company_id] => 1
                            [mapping_template_id] => 496
                            [created_by] => 2
                            [axis] => 0
                            [view_style] => fs
                            [sort_offset] => 
                            [calculated_offset] => 0
                            [property_id] => 415
                            [created_at] => 2021-04-05 21:11:31
                            [updated_at] => 2021-04-05 21:12:40
                            [last_uploaded_at] => 2021-04-05 21:11:31
                            [last_amenity_uploaded_at] => 2021-04-05 21:11:31
                            [notices] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [slug] => UUKF2oyn
                                            [file_type] => 2
                                            [seen] => n
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [slug] => UUKF2abc
                                            [file_type] => 2
                                            [seen] => n
                                        )
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Here you can see the nested results, like property version on its own levels and same goes for notices. I want something like this nested but only on notices level and I want to achieve it with query builder not eloquent.

Comment: I assume you're referring to JSON format?

Comment: Use relationships `belongsTo` and `hasMany` in your models. And then use `eager loading "with"` function to get the result

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look